Actionscript 3.0 Rotate child movieclip from center of parent
I have a parent movieclip (square shape with center registration point) When user clicks on it a movieclip (leaf shape with center registration point) gets added to the parent "n" times. I want want them to rotate from center of parent so as to form a flower
Following is the click function but it rotates from its own center point and not the parent
function onCreateClick(e = null):void{
if(currTool == "Shapes"){
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        shp = new shapesMc();
        par.addChild(drawArr[i-1]);
        shp.x = _mc.mouseX;
        shp.y = _mc.mouseY;
        shp.transform.matrix = new Matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);
        shp.rotation = i * 360 / n;
    }
  }
}

Current result vs End Result Required

The simplest way to do it is to create a proxy Sprite for each leaf, offset the leaf so that leaf stalk would start at proxy's (0,0), and then rotate the proxy. You can, of course, figure out the math to place leaves directly, but that would take some time and effort, would be far less readable and clear as a code, and there would be no noticeable performance benefits.
